Selenide перенаправляет на http
Есть вполне обычный код
baseUrl = "http://<неважно>";
open();

исполнение которого открывает нужную мне страницу по протоколу https.
Пробовал проделать тоже самое через selenium
new ChromeDriver().get("http://<неважно>");

и вуаля - нужная мне страница на нужном мне протоколе.
В чем может быть дело? Какие настройки нужно поменять? Буду благодарен за советы по делу.
Версии:

selenide:6.19.1
selenium-java:4.11.0
webdrivermanager:5.5.3
java 11
chromedriver 123

